# C# touch screen category selection

Tags: c#, windows, forms, layout

So I am creating a touch screen GUI for a device running windows, which steps the user though a few categories.

For example the Home screen is a borderless, maximised screen with a few buttons (Apple, Samsung, Windows phone... etc) and the user clicks the button, which opens a new form.

For example if the user clicks the Category item Apple, a new form will open and allow the user to choose iPhones or iPads... then again if you click iPhone, it will open yet another form. This next form will allow you to choose the model of iphone/ipad.

As you can see this is not a very convenient way of doing things, especially if a new product comes out and the form needs to be updated, or if there are large depth of categories. Also the layout of each forms are the same regardless of the category you are in.

Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe using one form, but the content of the form will change depending on which layer of category you are in? This must be scalable and easy to implement as it will later be connected to a database to populate the form with products in each category.

IDE: Visual studio 2013
Language: C#
Device Env: Windows OS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting an error or is this just a request for advice on how to proceed?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, other than the transition from one form to the other is not fluid, screen flickers when you show a form, then close the previous one. I'm requesting advice on a better way to do this task.

Comment: and is this for Windows Mobile development or all touch screen devices running Windows?

Comment: Touch screen device running windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93927/discussion-between-simon-price-and-user3684557).